# How to remove a row from the alembic_version table in flask app

Tags: python, flask

In my test application I use SQLite database and I had to reinstall flask-migrate

```
pip uninstall Flask-Migrate

pip install flask-migrate
```

Then I created a migration repository:

```
flask db init
```

When I migrate myself:

```
flask db migrate -m "users table"
```

I get the error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\newtestapp>flask db migrate -m "users table"
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
ERROR [root] Error: Can't locate revision identified by '0730f0aa078f'
```

If I understand correctly, then I need to remove the old version `0730f0aa078f` from the `alembic_version` table.

How do I delete a row from the alembic_version table using Flask-SQLAlchemy? 
If this is not possible, what other ways can this be done?

Thank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `alembic_version` table only ever has a single row, which stores the current version of the database schema. The easiest thing to do, since you're starting over, is just to delete the alembic_version table entirely and let `flask db upgrade` recreate it for you. As always, if there is something useful in your DB then **back it up first.**

Comment: How to completely remove the alembic_version table? With which command in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Comment: You shouldn't use Flask for this, you should do it manually by connecting to the database instance directly and removing the table. You've gone behind Alembic's back to reset the migrations, so you need to finish the job. Alembic can't help you with that. How you delete the table will depend on which database you're using. For Postgres, for example, the command would be `DROP TABLE alembic_version`.

Comment: If you have found this answer helpful, I'd appreciate it if you marked the question as solved.

Comment: Thank. Your answer  helped me